# Greatest common divisor with Map Reduce Apache Hadoop

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, parallel-processing, hadoop2

I am trying to implement GCD distributed algorithm using `Apache Hadoop` but cannot figure out it is possible to use Hadoop for this task.

I have simple function used to find GCD of two numbers.
But I need to implement GCD for array of numbers.
SO basically reduce an input array into small chunks of two numbers and than execute this function for each chunk and combine results.

```
private static int gcd(int a, int b) {
    int temp = 0;
    while (b != 0) {
        temp = b;
        b = a % b;
        a = temp;
    }
    return a;
}
```

I have tried but cannot figure out how to implement this using Apache Hadoop. Could someone please help with this task. Or provide the implementation of the similar algorithm to get better understanding how it works.

The input is an array of N numbers for example

```
20,520,320,5,60,30
```

And output should be

```
5
```

Comment: I do not really get what the input is. Do you want to calculate the `gcd` of a large array of numbers, or do you have "tuples" of two number for which you want to calculate the `gcd` for all these tuples separately?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thank for the reply , I have just update my question

Comment: Hint: `gcd` can be applied recursively: `gcd {a,b,c,d,e,f} == gcd(gcd(gcd(a,b),gcd(c,d)),gcd(e,f))`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem , yeah, I know how to implement this recursively, but how to do this using Hadoop ?

Comment: @bxfvgekdv: well based on what I've read you can only use hadoop for tail recursion?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I just need to implement GCD for an array of N numbers using Hadoop (Map&Reduce), but I newbie to Hadoop and can't figure out how to do this correctly, how to map and how to reduce an array of numbers and calculate GCD. I want just to understand how it works

Comment: single machine will calculate it faster than hadoop

Answer (score 0):

Check out this block. This should work to find gcd of array.

```
gcd=arr[0];
int j=1;
while(j<n)
{
   if(arr[j] % gcd==0)
   {
       j++;
   }
   else
   {
       gcd=arr[j] % gcd;
       i++;
   }
}
```